# Getting the json error response form the server while using the axios

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

```
Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/signup',
        {
            name:name,
            email:email,
            password:password
        })
        .then((res)=>{
            if(res.data){
                M.toast({html: 'Response successfully recorded!'}) //giving the message
            }
            console.log(res);
        })
```

I am using this piece of code for sending the POST request to the backend server in my react application, but am not able to get the json error given by the server insted I am getting this :-

```
xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:3001/signup 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 422
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

**How to get the json error given by the server for handling the error at the frontend side ?**

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `.catch` :

```
Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/signup',
{
    name:name,
    email:email,
    password:password
})
.then((res)=>{
    if(res.data){
        M.toast({html: 'Response successfully recorded!'}) //giving the message
    }
    console.log(res);
}).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

`.then` means the success of the request.

`.catch` means the failure of the request.